# How to get ubuntu GUI in Amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, bigdata

I am new to amazon ec2. I am trying to get ubuntu GUI on amazon ec2. Please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, but it is not as straight forward as just picking Ubuntu GUI AMI. You need at least some command line knowledge and SSH to get set up running "sudo apt-get install lxde". Following that, you can Remote Desktop to the server from Windows or [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC) from maybe your own personal Ubuntu machine.

[Quick guide to setting up Ubuntu with GUI enabled here.](http://www.comtechies.com/2013/02/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu.html)